# inherited_resources and cancan conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, inherited-resources

There are conflict with inherited_resources and Ryan Bates's cancan gem.

I have some simple controller

```
class IssuesController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :html

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def tag
    @issues = Issue.tagged_with(params[:tag]).recent.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  protected

  def collection
    @issues = end_of_association_chain.recent.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => Settings.per_page_defaults.issues)
  end
end
```

and route

```
  resources :issues do
    collection do
      get "tag/:tag" => "issues#tag", :as => "tags"
    end
  end
```

Everything looks correct, but on attempt to request http://localhost:8080/issues/tag/tag1
i see

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in IssuesController#tag

Couldn't find Issue without an ID
```

After removing load_and_authorize_resource from controller - everything works fine, but i need access control.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `load_and_authorize_resource :except => :tag`. Note that this wont apply rules. If you need to apply some use `authorize!` instead.